# Scala special char validation gives incorrect result

Tags: scala

I am trying to some validation on a scala string

It gives correct result for res0 only , All others are giving false which is wrong

I am expecting true for res1,res2,res3 as the string has a bad character in it

```
scala>  val badChars = Set( ',' , '-' , '\\' , '/' , '|' , '\t' )
badChars: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(\,         , |, -, ,, /)

scala> var str ="surender"
str: String = surender

scala> str.forall(badChars.contains(_))
res0: Boolean = false

scala> var str ="surender-"
str: String = surender-

scala> str.forall(badChars.contains(_))
res1: Boolean = false

scala> var str ="surender,"
str: String = surender,

scala> str.forall(badChars.contains(_))
res2: Boolean = false

scala> var str ="surender|"
str: String = surender|

scala> str.forall(badChars.contains(_))
res3: Boolean = false
```

Could someone explain me what went wrong here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[forall](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/StringOps.html#forall(p:A=%3EBoolean):Boolean) checks whether a predicate holds true for *all* the elements in a `String`.

One way to do your intended check:

```
str.exists(badChars.contains(_))
```

Answer (score 1):

`forall` only returns `true` if the predicate holds for *every* member. If you used `exists` instead, which returns `true` if the predicate holds for *any* member, your code would likely work as expected.

Comment: also, it's more fun to write, `str.exists(badChars)`.